# How to find which app build version is currently deployed on my android device?

Tags: android

I am returning to work on an old app that I left 7 months ago. The build that is deployed on my android is not up to date with the version control rather I have made **more** changes to the code in the hope of adding some functionality when I abandoned. The result is that the code running on the emulator now is different than what is running on my device. Now I want to get back to ***not the latest version in repository, not the one on the emulator*** but *the one that is deployed on my device*. Is there a way to find that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `badging` options of Android Asset Packaging Tool (aapt).

First you need to extract the APK from your device:

```
adb shell pm path com.example
```

The output will be like *package:/data/app/com.example-2.apk*

Then pull the APK with this command:

```
adb pull /data/app/com.example-2.apk
```

After that use aapt:

```
<sdk_dir>/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt dump badging com.example-2.apk
```

The output will be something like this:

```
package: name='com.example' versionCode='1' versionName='1.0.0'
```